# How do I save from tkinter input boxes to a text file without getting PY_VAR0 as a value?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am fairly confident with Python but have never used tkinter so I would really appreciate some help please/

I am trying to create a basic login system using tkinter and a text file. When I save to the text file it is just saving PY_VAR0 and PY_VAR1 to the text file, I have tried to use .get but the error says that str has no attribute .get

I have tried loads of stuff but have had no luck - I have a feeling what I'm doing wrong is glaringly obvious I just haven't realised it

Some of the code is probably completely useless here but I figured I would include it all as it may help you to figure out what is causing the problem

Can anyone please assist?

```
# importing librarys
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

#setting up window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Widgets Example')
window.title('All Planner_login')
window.configure(width=355, height=355)

def validateLogin(username, password):
    print("username entered :", username.get())
    print("password entered :", password.get())



winWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
winwHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
posRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - winWidth / 2)
posDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - winwHeight / 2)
window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))

fr = tkinter.Frame(window, height=175, width=295, bg='#1f85de', borderwidth=75)
fr.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
lblInst = tkinter.Label(fr, text='log in:', fg='#000000', bg='#1f85de', font=('Helvetica', 16))
lbl = tkinter.Label(fr, text="Username:", bg='#1f85de')
username = StringVar()
ent = tkinter.Entry(fr, textvariable=username)
lbl2 = tkinter.Label(fr, text='Password:', bg='#1f85de')
password = StringVar() 
ent2 = tkinter.Entry(fr,show='*', textvariable=password)
validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, username, password)
btn = tkinter.Button(fr, text='Login', command=validateLogin, fg='#a1dbcd', bg='#1aa831')

usernameSave=str(username)
passwordSave=str(password)

text_file = open("passdoc.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(usernameSave)
text_file.close()

text_file = open("passdoc.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(passwordSave)
text_file.close()




lblInst.pack()
lbl.pack()
ent.pack()
lbl2.pack()
ent2.pack()
btn.pack()
window.configure(background='#6b18ba')
window.mainloop()



#menu window
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title('ALL Planner')
window.configure(width=1000, height=600)
window.configure(background='#6b18ba')

winWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
winwHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
posRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - winWidth / 2)
posDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - winwHeight / 2)
window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))

fr = tkinter.Frame(window, height=500, width=900, bg='#1f85de', borderwidth=75)
fr.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
lbl = tkinter.Label(fr, text="Notes:", bg="#6b18ba")


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `usernameSave=str(username.get())` and `passwordSave=str(password.get())`

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Based on the description of the problem, it sounds like we don't need more than a single Entry widget, a function that gets the data and saves it, and enough extra code to make it work. It would also help if you posted the full error that you are getting.

Comment: Use the variables like you did in `validateLogin`. It would be a good spot for saving the values anyway.

Comment: Your writing the instance of `StringVar()` on to the text file with `n = text_file.write(usernameSave)`, what you should be doing is, what @Mike67 said, because you want to _get_ the value and write that onto the file. Also it is not recommended to use more than one instance of `Tk()`, replace all child windows with `Toplevel()`.